# Flexbox styling with React Native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

Well I thought I was getting the hang of styling. Tested on several different sized phones and it all looked great. Then... I tested on an iPad. Several of my screens ran way off the page. I am using flex: 1 for the container so I don't understand why. Do iPads not respect flex: 1 or something? Or did I just royally mangle the layout code? I thought using the screen dimensions and % to calculate most things would work for responsive design.

Example, sign in screen. Bottom 2 buttons "Login" and "Home" run almost completely off iPad screen. On phone devices seem to display fine.

EDIT: Thank you so much for the answer! I have rewritten the code and it looks fabulous now on the ipad. I hope this code is an improvement, I have added it to the bottom. Now to rewrite ALL the screens *facepalm*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { auth } from '../../src/config'
import AppText from "../components/AppText";
import colors from "../config/colors";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

let width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

function SignIn( { navigation } ){
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  function emailSignIn(email, password){
    email = email.trim();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function(result) {
      setMessage('');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      setMessage('Invalid Email or Password. Sorry :(');
    });
  }

  function updateEmail(email){
    setMessage('');
    setEmail(email);
  }

  function updatePassword(password){
    setMessage('');
    setPassword(password);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={require("../assets/logo.png")} />
      <Image style={styles.rainbow} source={require("../assets/rainbow.png")} />
      <View style={styles.bottom}>
        <View style={styles.inputView}>
          <TextInput
            style={{width: width * 0.8, textAlign: "center", padding: width * 0.02}}
            placeholder="E m a i l..."
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            onChangeText={(email) => updateEmail(email)}
            autoCapitalize = 'none'

          />
        </View>
    
        <View style={styles.inputView2}>
          <TextInput
            style={{width: width * 0.8, textAlign: "center", padding: width * 0.02}}
            placeholder="P a s s w o r d..."
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={(password) => updatePassword(password)}
            autoCapitalize = 'none'
          />
        </View>
 
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword')}>
          <Text style={styles.forgot_button}>Forgot Password?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <AppText style={styles.message}>{message}</AppText>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>emailSignIn(email,password)} style={styles.appButtonContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('StartScreen')} style={styles.appButtonContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>HOME</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default SignIn;
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  appButtonContainer: {
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor: colors.purple,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingVertical: "3%",
    width: width * 0.8,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  appButtonText: {
    fontSize: width * 0.04,
    color: colors.white,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    letterSpacing: 10,
  },

  bottom: {
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: width * 0.8,
  },

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },

  forgot_button: {
    height: width * 0.1,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

  image: {
    width: width* 0.5, 
    resizeMode: "contain",
    position: "absolute",
    top: -20,
  },
 
  inputView: {
    backgroundColor: "#d9f1ff",
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginBottom: width * 0.05,
  },

  inputView2: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffb8",
    borderRadius: 30,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 0,
  },

  message: {
    color: colors.red,
    marginTop: width * 0.05,
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
 
  rainbow: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "10%",
  },
 
});
```

New styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  appButtonContainer: {
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor: colors.purple,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginHorizontal: "5%",
    height: "25%",
  },
  appButtonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: colors.white,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    textTransform: "uppercase",
    letterSpacing: 10,
  },
  
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },

  forgot_button: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

  image: {
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
  },
  
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  inputButtons: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    marginHorizontal: "10%",
  },
 
  inputView: {
    backgroundColor: "#d9f1ff",
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: "25%",
  },

  inputView2: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffb8",
    borderRadius: 30,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: "25%",
  },

  message: {
    color: colors.red,

    alignSelf: "center",
  },
 
  rainbow: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
  },
  rainbowImage: {
   height: "60%",
   position: "absolute",
   top: "15%",
  },

  submitButtons: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
  },
 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `width` from `Dimensions` at the top level of your file and then basing all of your layout calculations on this later on. This means that whenever this file is first parsed/run, that `width` will be calculated. That'll work if the device reports its width correctly on the first pass through the code (not guaranteed), but will break if it gets an unusual width during that pass (likely) and will definitely break if the window changes size or rotates.

Instead of basing all of your calculations on that static `width`, I suggest you look into leveraging Flexbox for dynamic layouts.

For example, at one point in your code, you set a `TextInput` to 80% of the view by doing `width * 0.8`.  You could do the same thing by just setting the width to 80%:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <TextInput 
        style={{borderWidth: 1, width: "80%"}} 
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Basically, try to do everything you can to get rid of relying on `Dimensions` unless you really need it. And, if you do need it, make sure you calculate it at the time you need it based on the current screen and not just at the first run of the app.